# How can I run a program installed from a tar.gz file?

Tags: installation, compiling

I've recently installed ubuntu 12.10 and noticed that whenever I install any type of `tar.gz` software in the terminal, it says `installation finished` but I don't find the software.

example:

```
Checking dependencies
Python Version: 2.7.3
Found PyQt4
Found QtHelp
Found QScintilla2
Qt Version: 4.8.3
PyQt Version:  4.9.3
QScintilla Version:  2.6.2
All dependencies ok.

Compiling user interface files...
Compiling source files...
Installing eric4 ...
Installation complete.
```

I've tried installing several `tar.gz` files but it just doesn't appear in my software list 
even if I search for it the , it just isn't there.

Comment: What and how are you installing this software?

Comment: Software installed via tarballs does not get integrated into the package system which Ubuntu normally uses to index the software. Also, for installing eric I would simply install it from the software centre or via "apt-get install eric"